# Call function on controller each time view is displayed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am struggling to get my head around the following (simple?) situation....

I have a single page application and I am creating a new module / feature-set within it using AngularJS. However, due to events outside my control, it will be using jquery mobile routing.

The problem I have is that one particular view needs to pull data out of IndexedDb each time the view is displayed as there is a background data polling mechanism that may add / remove objects from indexeddb. Does Angular have something similar to a "pageshow" event that I can use to trigger the indexeddb lookups? I thought about creating a watch but I am concerned that this would be very resource intensive.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but jquery mobile routing just keeps the DOM and change the display state of different `pages` right?

If that's the case and controller isn't refreshed then watcher would be your solution, and one simple $watch won't have an impact on your app performance, although if the said changes comes from other views then you are better of with two-way data binding between controllers

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to do this

1- If that view has it's own controller , the best way to do this is to define a **resolve** property in the config like this

```
     app.config(function($routeProvider){
       $routeProvider.when('/YourView',{
        temlateUrl:"YourTemplate.html"
        controller:'YouteTemplateControler'
        resolve:{
         init:function(){
           alert("Hello from RESOLVE");
           // here you can call an $http request and return the data like this : 
           // return dataFromHTTPREQUESTCallBack;
                      }
           }
          // this function will fire before anything in your controller tries to fire
       })})
```

And later in your controller you can just use it like this

```
 youApp.controller('YourController',function($scope,init){
     $scope.data = init.data 

  });
```

2- You can call a function in your controller first lines like this :

```
   yourApp.controller('yourController',function(){
   init();
   function init(){
   alert("Hello from controller");
   // Keep in mind that if you have some dependency on this function that You will use in your controller , this is not a aschynchronous function , So its better to use **resolve** as I said in my first example
    }
 });
```